# Do two pairs of distinct natural numbers exist such that AGM(A,B) equal to AGM(C,D)?

Tags: means, natural-numbers

Here AGM is arithmetic-geometric mean.

Are there natural numbers A,B,C,D such that $1\leq A<C<D<B$ and arithmetic-geometric mean AGM(A,B)=AGM(C,D) ?

In other words, is AGM a homomorphism of an unordered pair of natural numbers on a set of real numbers?

Comment: Isn't $A<AGM(A,B)<B?$  How could this be true?

Comment: The questions in your title and body are different. In particular, the answer to the question in the body is trivially no: $AGM(A,B) \leq B < C \leq AGM(C,D)$, but the question in the title does not suffer from this problem. In particular, for any such example, we must have either $A < C < D < B$, or one of the obvious permutations of that.

Comment: Typo. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{AGM}(A,B) = \operatorname{AGM}(\sqrt{AB}, \frac{A+B}{2})$. If $A<B$, we have $A < \sqrt{AB} <\operatorname{AGM}(A, B) < \frac{A+B}{2} < B$.